# "curl_rule_01 declared as an array with negative size" error on built xcode 5 iOs7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, libcurl

I am trying to archive an iOS 7 App that is using BBHTTP-library which includes libCurl. The built-error:

```
curl_rule_01 declared as an array with negative size
```

The code-line in curlrules.h with the error:

```
[CurlchkszEQ(long, CURL_SIZEOF_LONG)];
```

I've tried it with these changes in curlbuild.h

```
#define CURL_SIZEOF_LONG 4
```

to

```
#define CURL_SIZEOF_LONG 8`
```

due to 64 bit, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Why isn't that `#define CURL_SIZEOF_LONG sizeof(long)`?

Comment: Yes, thanks! I added this line to curlbuild.h and it archives now. No idea why the library guys at libCurl did it the other way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Be careful: you must NOT change these macros inside `curlbuild.h`! This header is generated at configure time and it records (among other things) which architecture is targeted.

If you look at the pre-built static library provided by BBHTTP you can see that it only targets `ARMv7` and `ARMv7s` architectures:

```
$ otool -fV External/libcurl.iOS/libcurl.iOS.appstore.a | grep Archive
Archive : External/libcurl.iOS/libcurl.iOS.appstore.a (architecture armv7)
Archive : External/libcurl.iOS/libcurl.iOS.appstore.a (architecture armv7s)
```

These are 32-bit architectures. Please refer to [BBHTTP Dependencies](https://github.com/brunodecarvalho/BBHTTP#dependencies) for more details regarding how this static library has been compiled.

If you build an iOS app with iOS 7 as deployment target you certainly have the default archs configured within your build settings. And these defaults include a 32-bit slice, plus a 64-bit slice:

[image]

So in such a case you must include a **libcurl fat static library** that also contains a **64-bit slice** (a.k.a `arm64`).

The [curl iOS build scripts](https://github.com/brunodecarvalho/curl-ios-build-scripts) from BBHTTP's author might help you. Otherwise please refer to [Nick Zitzmann libcurl pre-built](http://home.comcast.net/~seiryu/libcurl-ios.html).